# MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM not working in live server

Tags: php

This is my password encrypting script:

```
/*....salting starts........*/
  $cost = 10;
  $salt = strtr(base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)), '+', '.');
  //$salt = sprintf("$2a$%02d$", $cost) . $salt;
  $options = array('cost' => $cost,'salt' => $salt);

  //$password = crypt($data['password'], $salt);
  $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT,$options);
  /*..........salting ends..............*/
```

ANd verify like this:

```
if (password_verify($this->password, $hashAndSalt)==true) {
         $status = "verified";
        $logged_in = 1;
        }else
        {
        $status = "not verified";
          $logged_in = 0;
        }
```

The above works perfectly fine localhost but not with live server.
 I guess my server is below php 5.0  and I guess  MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM only works with php 5.6 and above?

What's the alternative for  MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM please, without having to change the the verification method?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean in concrete terms?!

Comment: @deceze, unable to insert the record if this encryption is used. I tried without  encrypting the password, then can insert into database.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Have you checked?

Comment: "I guess my server is below php 5.0 and I guess MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM only works with php 5.6 and above?" - Why are you guessing? Did you check that already?

Comment: @deceze, no error shown.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php has a reference to https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat

Comment: @HannoBinder, I rememver i randomly  read this sometime ago, that's how guessed

Comment: Also, [`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) may be an alternative.

Comment: I think you should really *know* which PHP version is running on your server. - However, http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-create-iv.php says "(PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)", but see also the [change log](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-create-iv.php#refsect1-function.mcrypt-create-iv-changelog).

Comment: And really, using `password_hash`, you shouldn't be playing around with salts at all, unless you have a really specific reason to *manually* generate salts. Let `password_hash` do it for you.